# How can I run a command at login?

Tags: linux, script, fedora, automation

I would like to run a command at login on my Fedora 19 GNU/Linux system. What is the best way to do this?

Note: i am using the GUI. Thus, I could not simply place the commands in my .zshrc file. They are already in this file, but this file is not executed until I open a terminal window.

Comment: You should place the command inside /etc/rc.d/ files for specific runlevel or /etc/rc.local

Comment: That would be true for "on boot" not "on login" @Ashtray

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
gnome-session-properties
```

from either a terminal in gnome or through `Alt-F2` (just press the keys and enter the above command). This will give you GUI interface for doing exactly what you want. It is part of gnome-session package and I am pretty sure that it comes with F19 anyway. If a problem, then do as root from a terminal `yum install gnome-session` and then you will have the above command once yum finishes.